# How to view Windows eventlog items with GVim

Tags: windows, gvim

Is it possible to read the Windows-eventlogItems using GVim?
Our application logs errors in the eventlog, it would be nice if I could read them using GVim.

A daily export to file is not an option: it should be instant : error happens, switch to GVim, read details of the last X items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the events everytime you want to look at them.

**Route One**: Use `wevtutil` and `logparser` to create some .txt

```
 % wevtutil epl XYZ %TEMP%\log.evtx
```

Then you install [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) and use it like this:

```
 % logparser -i:evt -o:csv "SELECT * INTO %TEMP%\log.csv FROM %TEMP%\log.evtx"
```

After which you can

```
 % gvim %TEMP%\log.csv
```

Note: Replace 'XYZ' in the first line with whatever part of the event log you are interested at, these snippets should get you started.

Check out http://martin77s.wordpress.com/tag/logparser/ as well.

**Route Two**: Use [psloglist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897544) from Sysinternals and use it like this:

```
 :%!psloglist -h 1 -o XYZ
```

where XYZ is the event source (maybe the name of your app). Looks simpler to me.

Comment: Yes, I am hoping such an export tool exists, with possibility to filter last x items.

Comment: @akira: I thought the events are xml files on Vista/2008 onwards.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer

Comment: You might take a look at the Vim plugins that automatically translate non-text files when they're opened (e.g., $VIMRUNTIME/plugin/gzip.vim or $VIMRUNTIME/plugin/tarPlugin.vim) and see if you can do all those steps that akira gave automatically. Then all you would have to do is open the eventlog file with gvim and the text version would just appear.

Comment: @akira: I know that. I was suggesting that it might not be too much work to write one.

Comment: Thanks! tracking down errors has become much more easier now! something like psloglist is exactly what i was hoping for

Comment: @Sotto: if you like the answer then ... *cough* upvote *cough* :)

Comment: I tried upvoting before, but haven't got enough superuser reputation yet.. .sorry.  This is what i have in my _vimrc now (includes removing of ^M characters for easier reading) map <F10> :%!psloglist -h 5 application^M ^V| :normal ggd6d^M ^V| :%s/\r//g^M ^V| :normal gg^M

Comment: ^M .. just set ff=dos and they should be gone. upvoting: HA, time to write an answer or .. ask another question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can export the Event Log to an file.  In Windows 7 right click on the event category and choose "Save All Events As".  I believe that exists in previous versions of Windows as well.  Then you can edit that file with Vim.

Comment: using vim and clicking around like crazy just does not fit the mentality of a vim user, trust me :)